# How long does life support last indoors?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I read up on the milestones regarding surviving X sols on extreme weather planets and am aware that you are able to stand in a building, safe from the extreme external conditions while you twiddle your thumbs waiting for the milestones to hit. However, shortly after starting the wait, I realized that your life support drains despite being in a building that regulates all conditions.

Does anyone know an estimate for how long the life support module lasts in a regulated environment and how much each upgrade would affect this time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Life support is a part of your Exosuit, and its purpose is to keep you alive.

It's easier to understand if you think of life support as some kind of device that keeps you fed and hydrated, while your suit protects you from radiation, acid rain, and extreme temperatures. Even while indoor, you still need to eat and drink, thus life support keeps draining.

Some environments can make your life support drain more quickly than others, but there is no way to prevent it from draining at all.

Comment: If you do not have an exosuit module, it drains life support, doesn't it?

Comment: @Vemonus. I'd have to test that. I honestly don't know.

Comment: @Vemonus No, it starts eating away at your shields. Once your shields are down to zero, *then* you start taking health damage - and you've only got maybe 4-5 health IIRC.

Comment: @MageXy, ah you're right. I just checked and confirmed this.

Comment: "Life support has nothing to do with your environment" That's not accurate. There are planets with no effects on your exosuit, but that cause your life support to drop at an accelerated rate.

Answer (score 5):

Life support drains at the same speed indoors.  I have the level 3 upgrade (Tau) for it and I can tell you that it **significantly** slows down the drainage.  I would say with the level 3 upgrade it lasts close to 15 minutes before empty.

Comment: I haven't noticed a change in speed whether I was indoors or outdoors. I'll have to time it one day to verify.

Comment: Yeah, I would time it, but it would be quite a commitment. I was hoping someone had already taken the time to calculate the timing so I wouldn't have to :)

Comment: @Vemonus There are some situations where a planet's environment would impact life support duration, such as the "dust" atmosphere trait.

Answer (score 3):

Stacked it with the +2 and +3 upgrades all in a row to get the bonus.  Sitting in a shelter and not doing anything it took 1 hour and 20 minutes to get to 50%.

Comment: +1 for the effort; I have this same setup and noticed it was just over an hour for half